# odoo deployment in auto-scaling scenario

Tags: odoo, high-availability, odoo-13

I am trying to understand how to prepare a fresh server to deploy into a currently running cluster. Or as a replacement for a failed instance.

Other than the content of the source distribution (plus any added custom resources), what else needs to be deployed?

I have discovered images being served from the 'data_dir' filestore. Some resources like fontawesome files and certain icons are not being served.

Should the 'data_dir' location be shared between multiple instances in a cluster? And should it survive server failures?

Any other tips also appreciated?

Comment: data_dir is filestore. It needs to bee 1 on 1 with the database. If you share database hen you can share filestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment, Paxmees - you are right on the money!

Another thread from the Odoo community that also shed some light:
https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-exceptions-cachemiss-error-in-odoo-13-159480